# Suggestions for Importing CSV User Purchase History Data

Tags: users, feeds

I wonder about the most elegant solution for importing user history data.

I need to run a daily feed import of a CSV file to ingest the following user related purchase history.

```
uid,category,spent
1106,BED,2600
1106,BROOM,7800
2103,MANCH,89
```

Obviously, there can be multiple rows for a user.

Ideally, I would like to store the data in the user's profile. However, I have a couple of concerns.

Firstly, the only module I can think of for containing this data within the profile is field collection which I have had some frustrations with in the past. Secondly while I find the feed module a wonderfully easy solution for inserting/updating entities, but I'm not sure how to just import one field.

The other option I am considering of is importing to a content type called **"Purchase History"** that contains a reference to the the user. I haven't got time to create custom modules for this feature.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Elegant solutions typically require custom code ... so your question seems really broad if you're unwilling to do custom programming. You could try to use https://github.com/NuCivic/dkan_datastore  to store/upload the CSV file of records either once globally, or per-user (more work). DKAN makes an SQL table, you could then adopt this SQL table using the Data module and have VIEWS integration ... but dkan is abit of a chore to install and use. good luck.